# Laravel (OOP), model specfic array of values (for example titles of users)

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have model `User` and inside there is a field named `title`.

Now I want to define all possible titles. For example an array of

`['0' => 'Mr.', '1' => 'Ms.']`

What is the correct way to define these.

My idea is to create the `public function titles() { return ['0' => 'Mr.', '1' => 'Ms.'];` inside the `User.php` model and call for the array as `$user->titles()` whenever I need it. However this makes me twitch a bit because I'm calling the function on the model instance.

I really don't think creating a relation here is needed as there aren't more than ten possible titles.

Is there a better/right way to do these kind of things. I'm not that new to Laravel but I'm self thought so I'm trying to check my ways of doing stuff here.

I need to get into these oop basics a bit so any pointers here are helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You most likely want to use int's ad id.

Comment: Yup, I will change it in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to keep titles in config file, like:

```
'titles' => [
    1 => 'Mr.',
    2 => 'Mrs.'
    ....
],
```

Benefits are:

- you can edit this info at any time (keeping data hardcoded into model class is a bad practice)
- you can use this list as is for `select` list building
- you can keep data as `TINYINT` by keeping title IDs, sometimes it's a benefit

To build select list, do something like this:

```
{!! Form::select('titles', config('custom_config.titles'), 1) !!}
```

Comment: `keeping data hardcoded into model class is a bad practice` can you elaborate on this one? I don't really see a reason to save this data anywhere else but in `User` model since it's directly connected to it. But please do tell if I'm wrong on this one. All of the benefits you mentioned I have using it the way I used it in my exaple (I did change the array keys to integer, that was my bad :) ).

Comment: I've been exploring a bit more and this seems to be the way people do it so I suggest to people who are not sure to just go with the flow. I'm still looking for a good explanation about the `bad practice` thingey. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you want dynamic select box write this code

```
$titles = User::lists('title', 'id'); // controller

{!! Form::select('title', $titles, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}  // view
```

Comment: I think the titles will return all of the user instances (their id and title attribute) not the array of titles? Where are the titles defined in this example (which was my original question)? How did this get two upvotes in such a short time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use config files as @Alexey Mezenin suggested, but in this cases I prefer to use the database to store that kind of options (I mean in a different table, not in same users table), so I can add or delete options without touching the code and use the same form template/partial across different pages or projects if needed.

If you just need to retrieve the array it would be as easy as make a query in your controller and return it, but if you need it for form options I suggest you to use something like a form builder helper in which you get the form options from database and build your form using laravelcollective package, then you can pass the helper object to your view to show your fields and show whatever info you need.

Comment: I thought saving it in an array would be faster to retrieve as there won't be any filtering by it or anything similar that I would need the db relations for. To be honest, that's why I set the key and the value the same in the first example. However I have no arguments to support my claims so I was looking for someone with more knowledge to prove me right or wrong.